# Show progress indicator

Tags: c, linux, progress

I'm using C in Linux. How do I show a progress indicator that will let me know when the program (or parts of the program) will complete? For example, it could be something like "Searching...67%" and the percentage will keep increasing until the Searching portion ends.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you do something like:

```
while (perc < 100) {
    printf("Searching... %d%%\r", perc); 
    fflush(stdout);
    //do work
}
```

the `fflush()` is necessary to avoid the line buffering. Note that I am using `\r` and not `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

Write a `'\r'` character to stdout to return the cursor to the beginning of the line so you can overwrite the line. For example:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    printf("\rSearching...%d%%", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: I beat you by like 10 seconds, gj +1