# Print the percentage during a transfer

Tags: c, progress, percentage

This code is a portion of a FTP client that I have developed:

```
  for(size_to_receive = file_size; size_to_receive > 0;){
    nread = read(f_sockd, filebuffer, size_to_receive);
    if(nread < 0){
      perror("read error on retr");
      close(fd);
      return -1;
    }
    if(write(fd, filebuffer, nread) != nread){
      perror("write error on retr");
      close(fd);
      return -1;
    }
    size_to_receive -= nread;
  }
```

I would like to implement the percentage of the downloaded file but I have some problems. I've tried with this method:

```
  for(size_to_receive = file_size; size_to_receive > 0;){
    nread = read(f_sockd, filebuffer, size_to_receive);
    tx += nread;
    printf("%d%%\n", (tx * 100 / file_size));
    fflush(NULL);
    if(nread < 0){
      perror("read error on retr");
      close(fd);
      return -1;
    }
    if(write(fd, filebuffer, nread) != nread){
      perror("write error on retr");
      close(fd);
      return -1;
    }
    size_to_receive -= nread;
  }
```

but I don't like it because when the transfer starts, "20%" is immediately printed and also because if I remove the `\n` from `20%%\n` - `40%%\n` etc., the values are printed at the end of the transfer and not immediately.

How can I develop better code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show progress indicator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591264/show-progress-indicator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (size_to_receive = file_size; size_to_receive > 0;) {
    nread = read(f_sockd, filebuffer, size_to_receive);
    tmp_xc += nread;

    printf("%d%%\r", (tmp_xc * 100 / file_size));
    fflush(NULL);
}
```

Comment: far better solution.  Though you could easily modify it to only display ever increment of 20% :)

Comment: Better yet, you can use `\r` at the end to make it update in-place for a nicer UI.

Comment: What is the value of `file_size` that is causing this behavior?  Probably integer overflow.

Comment: i am an idiot!!!! i've declared the tmp_xc as an int xD you're right, I have encountered an integer overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ncurses**: [How to Create a WGet Like Command Line Progress Bar](http://juhaku.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/how-to-create-wget-like-command-line.html)

Comment: By the way, `cout` is the equivalent for `printf()`. I'm sure that you can find many progress bar examples in C using ncurses, on Google.